# Issue setting up dual-boot Mac OS and Zorin OS on 2017 MacBook Air

Tags: dual-boot, macos, zorin

I recently purchase a 2017 MacBook Air that came with a fresh install of Mac OS on it. Following a couple online guides, I was able to shrink the original partition of the HDD, and then re-partition the newly freed up space for a Zorin OS installation.

Here is what I want:

1. Obviously, on startup I would like to choose from either OS with one of them being default.
2. On my Linux partition, I would like to separate my home directory to keep that separate in case I ever want to switch to a different version of Linux.

I'm sure I did something wrong or am missing a step, but continues to happen is this. Upon installing Zorin OS, I am able to restart and boot into Mac OS. The applications in Mac OS work as expected.

When I restart and hold down the Option key during the startup, I am presented with two options to boot from. After connecting to the WiFi, I have discovered that it doesn't matter which option, I choose, it will boot into Zorin OS. Everything in Zorin OS works as expected.

From this point forward, restarting the MacBook will always boot into Zorin OS. The only way to get back to the Mac OS is to use the <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> combination to enter recovery mode. I then have to reinstall Mac OS in order to boot into it again. The odd thing is, the apps I installed previously are still there, so they don't get wiped out like I thought. I guess this is more or less "repairing" the system.

Regardless, this will always boot into Mac OS from this point forward, until I hold the Option key down on startup. Then the whole process repeats itself. I can no longer boot into Mac OS without reinstalling in recover mode.

Here's what the partitions look like (text version - attaching screenshots, also):

- `/dev/sda1` - 210 MB, EFI, mounted at `/boot/efi`
- `/dev/sda2` - 125 GB, Apple APFS, not mounted
- `/dev/sda3` - 8 GB, Linux swap
- `/dev/sda4` - 59 GB, Ext4, mounted at Filesystem Root
- `/dev/sda5` - 59 GB, Ext4, mounted at `/home`

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated. My apologies in advance, if this is something really dumb. I looked at several tutorials on how to do this, but none of them seemed to be exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve my issue after reading another tutorial that referenced a step I missed previously. All I needed to do was install [rEFInd](https://sourceforge.net/projects/refind/). This now displays the rEFInd GUI with the available boot options. I can select either the Mac OS or Zorin OS to boot into.